# Generics in Java - type erasure with abstract class

Tags: java, generics

I have generic class:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {
   T get(){
     return T;
    }
   ...
}
```

There are 2 classes:

```
public class CatService{
   MyGenericClass<Cat> generic;

   public CatService(MyGenericClass<Cat> generic){
   this.generic = generic;
   }
}

public class DogService{
   MyGenericClass<Dog> generic;

   public DogService(MyGenericClass<Dog> generic){
   this.generic = generic;
   }
}
```

I think it's better to create `public abstact class Service`:

```
public abstract class Service {
   MyGenericClass generic;

   public MyGenericClass (MyGenericClass generic){
   this.generic = generic;
   }
}
```

And make **CatService** and **DogService** **extend** this **abstract service**. 
They will initialize generic field in constructor calling **super(MyGenericClass generic)** or **super(MyGenericClass generic)**.

But In this case when I try to invoke MyGenericClass methods I recieve **"uncheked call"**, when I try to invoke T get() I must use **(Cat) generic.get()** OR  **(Dog) generic.get()**;

*Is It possible to avoid It?*

**UPDATE:** It's needed to specify generic type: **`extends Service<Cat>`**

```
public class CatService extends Service<Cat> {

   public CatService(MyGenericClass<Cat> generic){
   super(generic);
   }
}

public abstract class Service<T> {
   MyGenericClass<T> generic;

   public MyGenericClass (MyGenericClass<T> generic){
   this.generic = generic;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to make the parent Service class generic as well

Comment: `public abstract class Service<T> {
   MyGenericClass<T> generic;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `Service` class **generic** too.

```
public abstract class Service<T> {
   MyGenericClass<T> generic;

   public MyGenericClass (MyGenericClass<T> generic){
       this.generic = generic;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, what he (Elliott) said

Comment: I've tried.  It doesn't work when I use generic in DogService or CatService.There is still "uncheked call"